# Mysql performance: How to store files tree in the database?

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam

i am trying to store the files in the database and query the count and size of the folders. My Table is following.

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
`permission` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`size` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'filesize',
`date` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`time` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`path` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `path` (`path`(10)),
KEY `path_2` (`path`(4)),
KEY `size` (`size`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

my folders are like "????/some string". I have about 38,333,316 records.
The simple query takes about 22 seconds.

```
mysql> select count(*),sum(size)/(1024.0*1024.0*1024.0) from files 
where path like '5___%' and size != 2048;
+----------+----------------------------------+
| count(*) | sum(size)/(1024.0*1024.0*1024.0) |
+----------+----------------------------------+
|  7900746 |                        9019.6535 |
+----------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (22.89 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*),sum(size)/(1024.0*1024.0*1024.0) 
       from files where path like '5___%' and size != 2048;
--+-----------+-----+----+-------------- -+----+-------+----+--------+-----------
id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys   |key |key_len|ref |rows    | Extra     
--+-----------+-----+----+----------------+----+-------+----+--------+-----------
 1| SIMPLE    |files| ALL|path,path_2,size|NULL|NULL   |NULL|38333316|Using where
--+-----------+-----+----+----------------+----+-------+----+--------+-----------
1 row in set (0.23 sec)
```

Are there way to optimize the queries, can I speed up somehow?
Usually I expect to ask some questions similar to this:

```
path like '5___%' and size != 2048
path like '3___%' and size != 2048
path like '45__%' and size != 2048
```

Thanks Arman.

Comment: Do you need files that really are not 2048 in size or can they be greater than 2048 but smaller than 2048? If your query was size > 2048 that would significantly speed it up. Also, are you using default MySQL configuration or have you tried to tweak it?

Comment: File systems are pretty good at storing trees of files ;)

Comment: @Peter G.: the directories are nfs mounted each du -hs 5??? costs about 20-25 mins.

Comment: @Michael J.V.: Yes I need all records which are not directory eg: size>2048, but this does not help much. Concerning the my.cnf tweaking the second time the query stays in the cache so it takes milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `directories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `path` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `permissions` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `path` (`path`(4))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `directory_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `permissions` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `size` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `size` (`size`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(size)/1073741824 FROM files WHERE directory_id IN(SELECT group_concat(id SEPARATOR ',') FROM directories WHERE path LIKE '5___%');
```

Comment: thank you for the interesting solution. unfortunately it does not help in performance. the query status shows that it is in: Sending Data stage.

Comment: It seems that I have forgotten to put an index for `directory_id`, that might help too. In addition, you could just put a `size` field in the `directories` table and update it on new insertion/deletion - this would save you executing both the `SUM()` and a query to the `files` table, which is supposed to be extremely large compared to `directories`.